# Need to export data in excel and the after computing the data again need to store in salesforce

Tags: excel, salesforceexcelconnector

I have an excel file which contains several formulas. I need to take out some data from Salesforce into that excel file and after computing that data need to store the results back to Salesforce.
Any idea on how to proceed for this?

Comment: Why don't you just use Data Loader for this?

Comment: @RobinDeBondt I need to export the results into some preexisting excel file. And dataloader i think creates a new file.

Comment: You will probably have to do some copy-paste work anyway. You could just export it using Data Loader and exporting the columns in the order you have them in your file to save some work.

Comment: @RobinDeBondt Need automatic process.

Comment: You'll want to look into some ETL tools (Extract-Transform-Load) which can handle this request (the transformations will have to be configured in the tool itself rather than in a pre-existing excel file).

Answer (score -1):

You'd probably want to check out [CalcFusion](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000000pumNEAQ) on the AppExchange.

Disclaimer: I work at CalcFusion. If you find this answer helps at all, I'd be glad to assist you.

To give you an idea of what CalcFusion does, it transforms Excel into an API that can be plugged into Salesforce. You will have to upload your Excel into CalcFusion, and setup web services to send the variables from Salesforce to CalcFusion. Then, CalcFusion will execute the calculations using the formulas defined in your Excel, and then return the results to Salesforce using web services. You can do as you want with the results returned to Salesforce (display, save, etc.). If you wish, we have a Trial Account available and we would be happy to assist you on your first implementation. This is the first version of CalcFusion, we'd be happy to get your feedback on it.